# grep and cut a specific pattern

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cut

I have a a line and I want to get only the hash number :

```
2   Information example given false  d8a2e503-d8cf-4851-b809-82cc828efbbd   2020-08-23T13:07:22Z
```

the second field of string could change every time, it is for that I not use `awk '{print $1}'`

I want to get only the hash number : d8a2e503-d8cf-4851-b809-82cc828efbbd

I can grep with that : `grep -e "[0-9a-f]\{8\}-[0-9a-f]\{4\}-[0-9a-f]\{4\}-[0-9a-f]\{4\}-[0-9a-f]\{12\}"`

but cannot cut it

Comment: Why not `awk '{print $(NF-1)}'` to print the last but one field? See https://ideone.com/j3KZC4. Or, just use `-o` option with your `grep`

Comment: If you already have the regular expression, you can use sed: `sed -r 's/.*(RE).*/\1/'` where `RE` is your regular expression.

Comment: Did you try `grep -o`?